# I want to raise an event for a property without a local variable in C#

Tags: c#

When implementing the properties of c #, I know that if I add something more to the get set logic, I need to create variables to hold the values individually.

```
public class A
{
    int save;
    public int normal{get; set;} //Use as a variable
    public int property //Call event when value changes
    {
        get=>save;
        set
        {
            save=value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName=null)
        {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

The problem is that there are more "less meaningful" variables when there are more properties in this way. In the code above, save is never directly referenced and is only used to hold the value of the property.

For a simple get set property with no internal logic, the property itself appears to occupy one memory space soon.

I would like to simply call OnPropertyChanged in the above code without adding extra variables to the normal property.

```
public class A
{
    public int normalHope
    {
        get;
        set{
         //It keeps the incoming value in memory that is occupied by normalHope.
         OnPropertyChanged();
        }   
    }
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName=null)
        {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

Is there a way to implement this in C #?

Comment: there has been long request for such syntax as  public int someValue {get; set; notify; };  but MS did not implement this so far.

Comment: This is just the way it works, and everyone has to deal with it

Comment: There's not built-in way to do this, but there is a [add-in](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) for [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/) that implements this with fancy features like property dependency.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties), whenever you create an auto-implemented property, a private variable gets created by the compiler anyway:

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise **when no additional logic is required in the property accessors**. They also enable client code to create objects. When you declare a property as shown in the following example, **the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field** that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

So, it doesn't hurt much to add the private variables yourself *--only for the properties that you'd like to modify their getter/setter--* considering that it's the only way.

Just place them in a `#region`, collapse the region, and forget about them.